# Best way to log Journey Builder Email sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

**Use Case** 
I need to make sure that I send a specific email only once to a subscriber via Journey Builder.
**The Problem** 
The email is used in different journeys and I dont know where the subscriber will end up first.

**Approach** 
I know that I can make an insert into a data extension at send time within the email and add that data extension in an attribute group to the contact model. However, I was thinking about send log DEs and stumbled upon another Template called "Event DE Template". I cannot find any documentation on that. So I have no idea if that could be appropriate to use.

What would you consider doing? Is there something I did not think of?

Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here's my go-to process**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/) for Journey logging.

The gist is:

1. Create a status DE and relate it to the Contact in Contact Builder
2. Create a log DE to receive the status rows
3. Create a Query Activity in an hourly Automation that sweeps status rows to the log
4. Use the Update Contact activity in your Journey to record whatever you need

All your Journeys can use the same status and log DE.

Comment: Took me a while to get why you are doing what you are doing there. Nice solution.